# Don't throw PowerShell exception on writes to stderr from external command

Tags: git, powershell, error-handling

When an external command, such as git, writes to stderr, PowerShell generates a NativeCommandError exception. I would like to see the output normally along with stdout similar to how it might look on a standard UNIX/Linux system. There are a number of native commands that this script needs to run and I would prefer a solution that does not add too much clutter and maintenance to each command, if possible.

On Linux, a branch can be checked out as such:

```
$ git checkout devel
Branch 'devel' set up to track remote branch 'devel' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'devel'
```

The subtle part of that is that that last line was written to stderr for whatever reason. However, the exit status of git was zero indicating it was successful. Under PowerShell, I get this:

```
PS> git checkout devel
Branch 'devel' set up to track remote branch 'devel' from 'origin'.
git : Switched to a new branch 'devel'
At line:1 char:1
+ git checkout devel
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Switched to a new branch 'devel':String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Checking `$LASTEXITSTATUS`, it shows as zero indicating that the checkout was successful. However, because git's behavior is to write to stderr certain messages, it triggers PowerShell to register an error. I can just hide the message and check for the exit status manually, but I don't want to hide actual error messages when they show. This command does avoid the exception:

```
PS> git checkout devel 2>$null
Branch 'devel' set up to track remote branch 'devel' from 'origin'.
```

And is what other answers on StackOverflow have suggested, but isn't what I need. I've tried redirecting stderr to stdout with hope that PowerShell would see all output on stdout and not trigger an exception, but it still does:

```
git checkout devel 2>&1
Branch 'devel' set up to track remote branch 'devel' from 'origin'.
git : Switched to a new branch 'devel'
At line:1 char:1
+ git checkout devel 2>&1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Switched to a new branch 'devel':String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I have also tried catching the exception, but the try..catch block does not seem to block it:

```
PS> Try { git checkout devel 2>&1 } catch { echo "There was an error, ignore" }
Branch 'devel' set up to track remote branch 'devel' from 'origin'.
git : Switched to a new branch 'devel'
At line:1 char:7
+ Try { git checkout devel 2>&1 } catch { echo "There was an error, ign ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Switched to a new branch 'devel':String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I only want a native command to cause a failure if it had a non-zero exit status, not if it only writes to stderr. How do I prevent native commands in a PowerShell script from throwing an exception on writes to stderr without completely blocking stderr?

Comment: `try`  `catch` is only for _terminating_ errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when calling 3rd party executable from Powershell when using an IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095088/error-when-calling-3rd-party-executable-from-powershell-when-using-an-ide)

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari The highest voted and accepted answer is exactly what I said above I don't want. The second highest voted answer (wrapping it in cmd /c) achieves the right result, but it definitely into the ugly solution territory, the remain answers achieve the right result without much ugliness (using | %{"$_"}). Still a little ugly, but probably the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari Actually, even that is not quite a complete solution it seems. If $ErrorActionPreference is set to "Stop", it still registers an exception even though it comes out of stdout as a String. Also, I discovered a native Windows command that has the save behavior as Git. reg.exe import prints "The operation completed successfully." to stderr on success.

Comment: @penguin359, probably the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12866669/10155936) solves it ?

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr**

The simplest **workaround** for the PowerShell **ISE** is the following (*not* needed in a regular console or in Visual Studio Code):

```
# Redirect stderr (2) to the success stream (1).
# Doing so wraps stderr lines in [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]
# instances; calling .ToString() on them returns them as normal text.
# CAVEAT: BE SURE THAT $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' is NOT IN EFFECT.
git checkout devel 2>&1 | % ToString
```

<sup>For other workarounds, including the ability to distinguish lines by stream of origin, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54558444/45375).</sup>

However, you're **better off switching to Visual Studio Code** as your development environment, which solves the problem fundamentally - see below.

Two asides:

- What you're seeing are *non-terminating* errors, not exceptions (while .NET exceptions *underly* PowerShell's error handling, they are always wrapped in `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instances and may or may not abort execution (terminating vs. non-terminating error)).
- `try` / `catch` doesn't catch *non*-terminating errors, only terminating ones; while you could set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` beforehand to promote non-terminating errors to terminating ones, execution of your program (in the ISE ) would be *aborted* on receiving the *first* stderr line.

---

You can ***avoid* this problem** if you limit your PowerShell use to:

- a ***terminal* (console)**, including the upcoming [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal)
- **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)**; this cross-platform editor (IDE) is meant to supersede the [obsolescent Windows PowerShell ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support).

These environments behaves as you would expect:

- stderr (standard error) output is passed through to the display by default
- stderr lines print just like regular lines.

Note:

- **In the context of *remoting* and *background jobs*, stderr output is still sent to PowerShell's error stream**.
- There are **additional, host-independent problems with the use of `2>`** with external programs.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376457/45375) for a comprehensive overview of all problems.

Comment: this is the best answer that fully works, thanks

Answer (score 2):

> How do I prevent native commands in a PowerShell script from throwing an exception on writes to stderr without completely blocking stderr?

You can try, [with Git 2.16+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47232450/6309), the option I mentioned in "[PowerShell Capture Git Output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47367768/6309)"

```
 set GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR=2>&1
```

Check then if everything is written in stdout.

---

[zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59366288/dont-throw-powershell-exception-on-writes-to-stderr-from-external-command/59367795#comment132114877_59367795):

> The command shown here is for batch scripts.
>
> The actual PowerShell command to use is:
>
> ```
> $env:GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR = '2>&1'
> ```

Comment: This might fix Git, but I'd really prefer a generic solution, git was more of an example. I also discovered that even some Windows commands like "reg.exe import file.reg" will right this message to stderr: "The operation completed successfully." It's really frustrating that the PowerShell designers seem to have decided that any output to stderr means there was a failure and no clear method to turn that off.

Comment: @penguin359 I agree and only meant to address the Git part: test it out to see if at least that aspect would be remediated that way.

Comment: @zett42 Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.