# Any way to capture Windows specific exit codes in in git-bash?

Tags: cygwin, git-bash, msys2, msys

I have a scenario where a windows application that I execute in CI exits with `-1073740791` eg Stack Overflow. One cmd, this can be caught obviously via `%errorlevel%` but on bash, at least this exit code maps to `127` in `$?`.

Obviously, bash on windows should not break scripting so anything above or beyond 0-255 is not fine.

Question is: Is there any special variables or mechanism directly in git-bash itself to catch this actual value ? In this case, the executable is testsuite (think off google benchhmark or google test) and exit code 127 - command not found is not helpful at all.

Comment: The Windows inventors, in their infinite wisdom, decided that the exit code of a process can be any 32-bit number. Cygwin, which is modelled after Linux (respectively POSIX), the exit code is a 8-bit number, and even then, status codes of 127 and above are used for specific purposes (failure to start a program etc.) means that you effectively have only 7 bit available. You could write a wrapper batch script, which writes the long exit code to a file, and have your bash script evaluate this file.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and i do not think that there is any way to do that within bash.
I decided to wrap my executable in a powershell call, append the exit code to stdout and extract it afterwards like this:

```bash
OUTPUT=$(powershell ".\"$EXECUTABLE\" $PARAMETERS 2>&1 | % ToString; echo \$LASTEXITCODE")
# Save exit code to separate variable and remove it from $OUTPUT.
EXITCODE=$(echo "$OUTPUT" | tail -n1 | tr -d '\r\n')
OUTPUT=$(sed '$d' <<< "$OUTPUT")
```

Some notes:

- This solution does combine all stdout and stderr output into the variable $OUTPUT.
- Redirecting stderr in powershell wraps the output in some error class. Calling ToString() on these returns them as normal text. This is what the `| % ToString` is for. [Cmp. this SO Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376681/16814536)
- Invoking Powershell can be surprisingly slow due to Windows Defender. This can possibly be fixed by adding powershell to the [list of Windows Defender exclusions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26).